# Finding the points in a plane that are equally far away from two points outside the plane.

Tags: linear-algebra

The plane is given: $2x-y+z-3=0$.
The point $P=(3,-4,2)$ is on one side of the plane and the point $Q=(-2,6,7)$ is on the other side of the plane. How do I determine the points in the plane which are equally far away from both $P$ and $Q$?

I tried to put PS = QS, but that didn't work. I really don't know what to do here.

Accidently left out that the points i need to find must be IN the plane $2x-y+z-3=0$

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far. Also, you might like to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in future :)

Comment: The set of points equidistant from $P,Q$ is a plane. One way is to find this plane and find the intersection with he other plane, which will be a line.

Comment: What is the role played by the given play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S=(x,y,z)$ be point in the plane equidistance to the 2 given points $P$ and $R$
Through the distance formula (leaving off the square root) we have:

$(x-3)^2+(y--4)^2+(z-2)^2 = (x--2)^2 + (y-6)^2 + (z-7)^2$
Working this out, we end up with $x-2y+z=-6$ (Please check)

So now you have to find the line that intersects $x-2y+z=-6$ with $2x-y+z=3$ That line contains all the points we are looking for. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks! I think I can solve it now.

Comment: @AliMustafa GREAT!

Answer (score 0):

The set of points at an equal distance from two given points is a plane which is perpendicular to the line joining the two points. The difference between the two points is a vector parallel to such line. Writing the planes perpendicular to a given vector is immediate. Finally force the plane to pass through the midpoint of the two given points.